# SQLAlchemy Python with Flask on AppEngine: OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)")

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy

I'm using an app with Flask on Google AppEngine, I configured the database with this constant SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:pass@ip_address/database'. But on production machine shows this error:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)")
```

I configured correctly the lib with requirements.txt and I added the MySQLdb on app.yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

On production you should use this kind of syntax for your SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI

```
mysql+mysqldb://root@/<DATABASE_NAME>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<APPENGINE_PROJECT>:<SQL_INSTANCE_ID>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. Thank you, I was just helped by this! It's tricky because that syntax doesn't work locally IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled billing?  The first restriction on sockets -

> Although App Engine supports sockets, there are certain limitations
>   and behaviors you need to be aware of when using sockets:
>
> Sockets are available only for paid apps.

Comment: I had enabled the billing, but I will try use the unix_socket to connect, I saw many people with this problem. Thank You Tim Hoffman.

Comment: It is true that Sockets are available only for paid apps, however this error is just for bad configuration of SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI